# how to to get childs node with 'html agility pack'

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

how to to get childs node with 'html agility pack' ?

```
var Webget = new HtmlWeb();
var doc = Webget.Load(url);
HtmlNode elementbyId = doc.GetElementbyId("nome");
```

I just need to take internal node in `<div id="nome">`

html :

```
<div id="nome">
    <p> <!-- this node --> 
    <strong></strong>
    </p>
    <br/><!-- this node --> 
    <span><!-- this node --> 
    <strong></strong>
    </span>
    <p><!-- this node --> 
    <span></span>
    </p>
</div>
```

update :

I wrote the following code, but it is wrong.

```
var nodes = elementbyId.Descendants();
```

this code Get all the elements inside  `<div id="nome">`

Is there a way to solve the problem? I have no idea

Comment: what have you tried ? HtmlNode should have some property referencing child nodes.

Comment: what node do you need ?

Comment: mark with <!-- this node -->

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `SelectNodes("*")` instead of `Descendants()` to get direct children elements of current element. Here is a working example :

```
var html = @"<div id='nome'>
    <p> <!-- this node --> 
    <strong></strong>
    </p>
    <br/><!-- this node --> 
    <span><!-- this node --> 
    <strong></strong>
    </span>
    <p><!-- this node --> 
    <span></span>
    </p>
</div>";
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
HtmlNode elementbyId = doc.GetElementbyId("nome");
var nodes = elementbyId.SelectNodes("*");
foreach (var htmlNode in nodes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(htmlNode.OuterHtml);
    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------");
}
```

**<kbd>[Dotnetfiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xbAhsW)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
<p> <!-- this node -->
    <strong></strong>
    </p>
-----------------------
<br/>
-----------------------
<span><!-- this node -->
    <strong></strong>
    </span>
-----------------------
<p><!-- this node -->
    <span></span>
    </p>
-----------------------
```

Comment: Elements need one parameter. Elements(string name)

Comment: error : No overload for method 'Elements' takes 0 arguments

Comment: @testStack Updated with working alternative. (Actually, that kinda strange. I was able to run the original codes on PC. Output section also was copy-pasted from console output)